# Trouble with relationship set up in my laravel 4 app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

I'm having trouble with relationship set up in my laravel 4 app. I have two tables, Events and Event Types. I'm trying to access the name of the event type in the event show and index pages but I'm getting an error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name
```

My models are

```
class Event extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'events';

    public function eventtype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('EventType');
    }
}



class EventType extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'event_types';

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('Event');
    }
}
```

In my view i have

```
 {{ $event->eventtype()->name }}
```

but that gives the error above.

When I try to use

```
 {{ $event->eventtype()->first()->name }}
```

or

```
 {{ $event->eventtype->first->name }}
```

I get an error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Do I need to access the EventType in  the EventController@show or is there  pivot table needed to be able to achieve accessing the event type name in the event show view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In my events table the event type column name was event_type_id. I changed it to  eventtype_id and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$event = Event::with('eventtype')->find(1);
$event->eventtype->name;
```

Or this for multiple events:

```
$event = Event::with('eventtype')->get();
$event->first()->eventtype->name;
```

Comment: I used $event = Event::with('eventtype')->find(1) in my event show method and $event->eventtype->name in my show view but get Trying to get property of non-object error.

Answer (score 0):

First check related model exists and ONLY AFTER get model property!

```
@if ( $event->eventtype )
   {{ $event->eventtype->name }}
@endif
```

When you call $event->eventtype() as function this DONT get you a model, it get you QueryBuilder, you can use it for:

```
$some_events = $event->eventtype()->whereType('some_type')->get();
```

And it give you a models collection. To get model use property style call. Good luck!

Comment: Another words, when you use this code: `$event->eventtype->name` Laravel uses **dynamic properties** and converts it in `$event->eventtype()->first()->name` automaticaly.